# Python regex: remove short lines

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with multiple newline symbols:

```
text = 'foo\na\nb\n$\n\nxz\nbar'
```

I want to remove the lines that are shorter than 3 symbols. The desired output is

```
'foo\n\nbar'
```

I tried

```
re.sub(r'(\n([\s\S]{0,2})\n)+', '\nX\n', text,  flags= re.S)
```

but this matches only some subset of the string and the result is

```
'foo\nX\nb\nX\nxz\nbar'
```

I need somehow to do greedy search and replace the longest string matching the pattern.

Comment: I would suggest not doing this with a single regex, but instead first split on `\n` and then only keep the strings of length 3 or more.

Comment: Why do you desire `'foo\n\nbar'`? That still contains a line shorter than three symbols.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Good point, but in the rest of my document paragraphs are separated by double \n and I want to keep the same structure here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.S` makes `.` match everything including newline, and you don't want that.  Instead use `re.M` so `^` matches beginning of string and after newline, and use:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'foo\na\nb\n$\n\nxz\nbar'
>>> re.findall('(?m)^.{0,2}\n',text)
['a\n', 'b\n', '$\n', '\n', 'xz\n']
>>> re.sub('(?m)^.{0,2}\n','',text)
'foo\nbar'
```

That's "from start of a line, match 0-2 non-newline characters, followed by a newline".

I noticed your desired output has a `\n\n` in it.  If that isn't a mistake use `.{1,2}` if blank lines are to be left in.

You might also want to allow the final line of the string to have an optional terminating newline, for example:

```
>>> re.sub('(?m)^.{0,2}$\n?','','foo\na\nb\n$\n\nxz\nbar') # 3 symbols at end, no newline
'foo\nbar'
>>> re.sub('(?m)^.{0,2}$\n?','','foo\na\nb\n$\n\nxz\nbar\n') # same, with newline
'foo\nbar\n'
>>> re.sub('(?m)^.{0,2}$\n?','','foo\na\nb\n$\n\nxz\nba\n') # <3 symbols, newline
'foo\n'
>>> re.sub('(?m)^.{0,2}$\n?','','foo\na\nb\n$\n\nxz\nba')  # < 3 symbols, no newline
'foo\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use `re.findall` instead:

```
text = 'foo\na\nb\n$\n\nxz\nbar'

import re

print (repr("".join(re.findall(r"\n?\w{3,}\n?",text))))

#
'foo\n\nbar'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex, which looks for any set of less than 3 non-newline characters following either start-of-string or a newline and followed by a newline or end-of-string, and replace it with an empty string:

```
(^|\n)[^\n]{0,2}(?=\n|$)
```

In python:

```
import re
text = 'foo\na\nb\n$\n\nxz\nbar'
print(re.sub(r'(^|\n)[^\n]{0,2}(?=\n|$)', '', text))
```

Output

```
foo
bar
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/RRSJ11421)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use regex for this.

```py
raw_str = 'foo\na\nb\n$\n\nxz\nbar'

str_res = '\n'.join([curr for curr in raw_str.splitlines() if len(curr) >= 3])
```

`print(str_res)`:

```
foo
bar
```